# Checking on time range

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this meeting area reservation system. For setting the time-in and time-out for area reservation, I have use selection box

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group"  >

                                    <select class="form-control" id="time_in" name="time_in">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
                                        <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
                                        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                                        <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
                                        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                                        <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
                                        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                                        <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
                                        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                                        <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
                                        <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                                        <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
                                        <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                                        <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                                        <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                                        <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
                                        <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                                        <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
                                        <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                                        <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
                                        <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                                        <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
                                        <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                                    </select>

                                    <span class="select-arrow"></span>
                                    <span class="form-label">Time In</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="time_out" name="time_out">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="07:00">07:00</option>
                                        <option value="07:30">07:30</option>
                                        <option value="08:00">08:00</option>
                                        <option value="08:30">08:30</option>
                                        <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
                                        <option value="09:30">09:30</option>
                                        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
                                        <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
                                        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
                                        <option value="11:30">11:30</option>
                                        <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
                                        <option value="12:30">12:30</option>
                                        <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
                                        <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
                                        <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
                                        <option value="14:30">14:30</option>
                                        <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
                                        <option value="15:30">15:30</option>
                                        <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
                                        <option value="16:30">16:30</option>
                                        <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
                                        <option value="17:30">17:30</option>
                                        <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
                                    </select>

                                    <span class="select-arrow"></span>
                                    <span class="form-label">Time Out</span>

                                </div>
                            </div>
```

my table for the database looks like this :

dbname : **reservation**

```
id | emp_id | emp_name | local_no | meeting_area | time_in | time_out |
1     2335      jack       361        area 1         7:00     8:00
```

what i want is to make the `onChange` event and pass it to `ajax` to make an alert whether the selected time range of the user is already occupied or not..

the problem is I'm still new to php so I don't know how to do this..

anyone want to help me for this?

Comment: Show us your php code and ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you whole solution just some idea/steps you need to take in order to solve it.
On select change function you make Ajax call:

```
$("#time-in").change(function() {
var timeIn = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "url_to_your_php_method_that_will_handle_this_call",
   data: { 'timeIn': timeIn, 'empId':empId }, // you need somehow to get emp_id for one that you are checking 
   success: function(response){
     // Here you will handle response, that is show message if response does not satisfy condition
   }
});
});
```

In your php file you need to write logic which would look something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST["timeIn"] && !empty($_POST["empId"] )) {
    // write query to get all reservations for employee
    // Loop through fetched reservations and check for each reservation if  $_POST["timeIn"] is between fetched time_in and time_out, find a answer how to compare times in php
    // if it is return true, if not return false
}
```

And then in your success just check if response is true, if it is then alert message that user is already occupied, else nothings happens. 
You would do same for time-out select.

Comment: What if the reservation starts before the previously booked slot, but ends during/after?

Comment: Yes, I said that he should do the same for time_out time. That means to check time_out value is between fetched time_in and time_out.

Comment: Ah, well the test for overlaps is simpler than that